# Show errors in Razor ViewEngine

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how i can input detailed information about errors?
i was trying set `customErrors mode` to `On/Off`, but i have only: `Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, once you enable `customErrors` it's the contents of the `~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` file that you are seeing. You can customize it. It is strongly typed to a `System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo` model and you can extract the exception inside:

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    View.Title = "Error";
}

<h2>
    Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
</h2>

<div>@Model.Exception.ToString()</div>
```

You also have access to the controller and action that raised the exception inside the model:

```
@Model.ControllerName
@Model.ActionName
```